# Should I use as many or as few views / view controllers as possible?

Tags: ios, uitableview, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I writing an app that has many table views and depending on a number of factors those table views might show some sections and hide others.

I have, for instance, "active" objects and "archived" objects. When a user selects one he is taken to a same table view, but if the object is active some sections are shown and if it's archived other sections are shown. Now I'm thinking of adding other properties to those objects, like "finished", besides "active" and "archived". The thing is that the code for that table view controller is getting more and more complicated trying to figure out which sections to show or to hide depending on each property of the selected object. So I'm thinking of using different table views, one for archived objects, another for active objects, another for finished objects. But although they have many different sections there are also some sections in common that should be shown for all those objects.

So what should I do in a situation like this? Should I use three different table views with three different view controllers, one for each property of my objects (and I might even add more!), and repeat the same code many times for the sections that are common between them, or should I keep using one view controller and make its code more and more complicated trying to determine what sections to show or to hide? Or should I do something in between? Or something else entirely?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

---

Edit: I didn't think this was a matter of opinion, but apparently it is. There must be some objective things to consider, though. What's the impact of having many unnecessary scenes in a storyboard, for instance? Is it so negligible that it would be ok to create a new scene for every little change instead of doing things programmatically in the same view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you should have 3 separate view controllers.

While you develop and refine your app, you will definitely notice you have repeated code in a lot of places. When you notice that repeated code, try and abstract it into your Model layer and out of your View / Controller layer.

If you ever get to a point where your 3 controllers end up being almost identical, then you can combine them.

There isn't a definitive right or wrong answer to this; its a problem that you will learn to recognize and solve with experience.

Good luck with your app! :-)

Comment: Alright, I'll try to do that then. Thank you!